# How to UNION sub-query in T-SQL

Tags: .net, sql-server

I am trying to run the below code in SQL Server and unable to do so.

```
select * from ( 
  select 1,'Arun Kumar' union all
  select 2,'Arun Kumar' union all
  select 3,'Arun Kumar' union all
  select 4,'Arun Kumar'
)
```

The error message is

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6. Incorrect syntax near ')'

Could anyone please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can set alias name to your column and this work perfectly :

```
select * from ( 
select 1 as c1,'Arun Kumar' as c2 union all
select 2 as c1,'Arun Kumar' as c2 union all
select 3 as c1,'Arun Kumar' as c2  union all
select 4 as c1,'Arun Kumar' as c2 ) res
```

Comment: This works since we need to provide alias for column names too. Thanks.

Comment: There is no point in repeating the aliases in any query beyond the first in the union, as they will just be ignored.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using subquery as a tabe in `select ... from`  query, you MUST provide alias, so your query should look like. Moreover, you need to provide alises for columns as well:

```
select * from ( 
  select 1 [Column1],'Arun Kumar' [Column2] union all
  select 2,'Arun Kumar' union all
  select 3,'Arun Kumar' union all
  select 4,'Arun Kumar'
) aliasName
```

Comment: We need to provide alias for columns too. Earlier i tried just for the table and it threw an error.

Comment: @ArunKumar Yes, you are correct, but you need to do it only for first `select` :)

Comment: or just do it at the table alias name `aliasName ( [Column1] , [Column2] )`

Answer (score 3):

I prefer using a CTE for this situation:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 1 AS id, 'Arun Kumar' AS name UNION
    SELECT 2, 'Arun Kumar' UNION
    SELECT 3, 'Arun Kumar' UNION
    SELECT 4, 'Arun Kumar'
)

SELECT id, name
FROM cte;
```

I prefer the CTE syntax, because it easily lets us refer to the same CTE more than once when building a query.  In fact, when setting up demos for SQL questions here on Stack Overflow, this is what I end up doing most of the time.

Note: Because your `id` values are different on every record, we can just use `UNION` instead of the less performant `UNION ALL`, since there cannot be duplicate records.

Comment: Interesting answer using CTE. I was testing so i just used UNION ALL instead of UNION.

Comment: OP got it right by using UNION ALL (Since UNION ALL does not remove duplicates).